# image classification - predict image label

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, classification, multilabel-classification

I try to build simple image classifier like this one
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification

.

In the same time I want to print images labels on random images from ( specific separate test images folder )

Just like this photo https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification_files/output_oZTImqg_CaW1_0.png

and this code ( my problem with ) class_names and train_labels

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
for i in range(25):
    plt.subplot(5,5,i+1)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.imshow(train_images[i], cmap=plt.cm.binary)
    plt.xlabel(class_names[train_labels[i]])
plt.show()
```

in this page
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification#preprocess_the_data

my code it is copied from first link BUT I changed the dataset

```
PATH = r"C:\Users\memo-omen\Documents\py proj\i8mx1\dataset"


train_dir = os.path.join(PATH, 'train')
validation_dir = os.path.join(PATH, 'test')

train_cats_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'cats')
train_dogs_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'dogs')
validation_cats_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir, 'cats_test')
validation_dogs_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir, 'dogs_test')
```

etc. As I said same code but I use a local dataset

.

.

.

folders structure

c:\dataset folder (main)

-

dataset \ train (folder)

dataset \ train \ dogs (folder)

img1.jpg

img2.jpg

dataset \ train \ cats(folder)

img1.jpg

img2.jpg

-

dataset \ test(folder)

dataset \ test\ dogs (folder)

img1_test.jpg

img2_test.jpg

dataset \ test\ cats(folder)

img1_test.jpg

img2_test.jpg

Comment: is class_names a dict()? Can you show the first 3-5 items in the class_names and train_labels

Comment: thank you for helping, may you see last part of question after editing, and for you question I didn't used class_names of train_labels before, I just copied them from "Basic classification: Classify images of clothing" page to test the base code from first page "Image classification (cats and dogs)", and predict test images that I explained in "folders structure", thank you again for helping.

Comment: any help .?////